# How to find glitch in the dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, dataset

Nowadays, I'm facing a problem that here have some datasets that contain glitches. Like in a dataset has a number column. externally can easily be recognized that the maximum field has numbers. But its datatype is Object. Not only that some of the fields have non-numeric values.
for example:
A dataset has "**Age**" column: **[23, 34, 54, 33, pp, 27, 43]** and its datatype is object.
Now, Chake this out it has a string value "***pp***" into the number value. what we have known as a glitch in the dataset.
Now my question is how can I found those rows that contain the glitches like "***pp***".
[Here is an image of what I want to discuss with you](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTe7b.png)

Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried? please see [mcve] and [ask] images are not valid or reproducible examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with coercing errors (from non-numeric values) to `NaN`, and then check for `NaN` with [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html).  Then, use `.loc` to locate the row(s) with those `NaN` values (from non-numeric values):

```
df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce').isna()]
```

**Demo**

```
data = {"Age": [23, 34, 54, 33, 'pp', 27, 43] }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[pd.to_numeric(df['Age'], errors='coerce').isna()]

  Age
4  pp
```

Answer (score 0):

DataGlitch can differentiate between dtypes in columns.

```
from DataGlitch.dtype_detector import find_numeric

numeric, ambiguous, non_numeric = find_numeric(df["col"])
```

Any non numeric values will be in the non_numeric subset that is returned. You can then remove them with:

```
df = df[~df["col"].isin(non_numeric)]
```

More info in the docs:
https://pypi.org/project/DataGlitch/0.0.2/#description